# Direct access to full string representation of object

Tags: vb.net, smo

I am trying to log the contents of an object to a text file.  If I do a `debug.print` of the object itself in the immediate window, it prints all of the values of the object's properties:

```
?mDb.DatabaseOptions
{Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseOptions}
    AnsiNullDefault: False
    ...
    UserData: Nothing
```

However, I can't seem to access this as a string in code due to a type mismatch.  I assumed I could get this information using the `.ToString` method, but all that returns is the object description with none of the properties or values:

```
?mDb.DatabaseOptions.ToString
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseOptions"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like I'll need to use reflection.  I'm having some trouble actually implementing that so I've posted a follow up question: [Using reflection to mimic Debug.Print in VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8973859/154439)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.ToString is a function on the base object (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx).  Debug.Write is a function that can iterate though the properties writing the values.

As Stu said you can do this yourself using Reflection.

You could also add/change the trace listeners to write out the information else where.

Answer (score 1):

Debug.Print enumerates all properties for you. Is that what you are looking for? If so, you will have to examine all properties through reflection.